# Django filter objects by distinct fields and get the latest items

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model defined as:

```
from django.db import models

class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def latest_book(self):
        return super(BookManager, self).get_queryset().filter(something)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    objects = BookManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s : %s : %s" % (self.name, self.author, self.version)
```

A book with same name and author is considered as the same book, but they can have different versions. I want to filter out the latest (by comparing version) book of (name + author), for example:

There is such books:

```
Good Time : Andy : 1
Good Time : Andy : 2
Good Time : Andy : 3
My Django Book : Jim : 1
My Django Book : Jim : 2
My Django Book : Jim : 3
Python Tutorial : Tom : 1
Python Tutorial : Tom : 2
Python Tutorial : Tom : 3
Python Tutorial : Tom : 4
Python CookBook : Tom : 1
Python CookBook : Tom : 2
```

I want to filter it with:

```
from books.models import Book
Book.objects.latest_book()
```

And get expect result as:

```
 <Book: Good Time : Andy : 3>
 <Book: My Django Book : Jim : 3>
 <Book: Python Tutorial : Tom : 4>
 <Book: Python CookBook : Tom : 2>
```

How can I write the filter ( filer(something) in above code)?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

```
from django.db.models import Max
Book.objects.values('name', 'author').order_by().annotate(version=Max('version'))
```

Comment: Any way to get the model instances instead of values? Though I can get that by query again with these values, but not good in case I have a huge number of records. And this makes it a little hard if I want to do it within get_queryset.

Comment: Remove the `values` call and you will have clean models.

Comment: Hi Gianluca, what do you mean by 'remove the values call'? could you help to show me the exact line?

Comment: @vts which database you are using

Comment: @itzmeontv, I need this to be able to run with sqlite, postgres and mysql, I know postgres has distinct which may help on this, but I need a common solution.

Comment: @vts If you want the `Book` object instead of a dictionary use: `Book.objects.order_by().annotate(version=Max('version'))`. This will work with all the databases thanks to Djangos ORM.

Comment: @GianlucaMancini seems not work, it gives me all the records, with  `Book.objects.order_by().annotate(v=Max('version'))` , changed version to v to avoid error of 'The annotation 'version' conflicts with a field on the model'.